# Relative layout with Percentage height and width

Tags: java, android-linearlayout, android-imageview, android-relativelayout

I need something like Relative layout with percentage height and width to implement layout below . when i used Linear layout , i couldn't set margin and rotation properly for imageviews . and if i use Relative layout and set Imageviews height and width in `dp` type , they won't be resized to fill empty spaces in larger screen sizes.
Any suggestions are welcome

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Android's `ConstraintLayout` that was released within the last year can achieve percentage based layout sizing. [Check out the official documentation page](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html#add-a-constraint) for more details on how to apply it to your implementation.